# How to delete contents of Map?

Tags: java, dictionary

So I had built a program, and everything seemed to be going fine until I got to the debugging stages. And one of the big problems I found was that the `LinkedHashMap` I had been using was not actually deleting it's previous contents when I called `map.clear()` at the end of the loop. So I was wondering if anyone knew or could show me a good iterative way to delete the contents of a map?

Comment: Can you show your code, so that we know what you're talking about?#

Comment: I would like too, but the code is way too extensive and fragmented to be post. Apologies.

Comment: If your code is too complex, you should create a simpler example and test whether it's really a problem of the Map implementation (I can't believe it :-).

Comment: I have to agree with home. It seems unlikely that the Map implementation is at fault here and it is likely to be a different problem with your code. Without a sample, we can only guess.

Comment: Yeah, I think you guys are right. Not sure what the problem is, but it looks like clear (in terms of it's functionality) should do what I'm looking for. However, it is not being cleared properly for some reason in my code. I'll tinker around with it a bit and if I can't figure it out, I may just have to post the code outright for some help. Thank you for all your input though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This perfectly works in Open JDK 1.6. And if you look into the source for LinkedHashMap, there's simply no chance this cannot work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> test = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    test.put("a", "1");
    test.put("b", "2");
    test.put("c", "3");
    test.put("d", "4");

    System.err.println(test);
    test.clear();
    System.err.println(test);
}
```

EDIT: Does this describe your problem?

Comment: Yes, essentially that is the core of the problem. However, are you trying to say clear should be deleting the contents? Because it certainly isn't working for me lol.

Comment: So something else is wrong :-) Look into your JDK's source code - it **must** work. Is your app multithreaded, maybe you call `clear` on the wrong object? Does the map contain an indirect reference to itself?

Comment: Just tested out this solution like you were talking about above and you are correct, it does work fine in this context. Have no idea why it is not properly being cleared in my program :/

Comment: BTW: If you find the problem, please update your question or this answer... seems to be interesting though.

Comment: Just found the solution. It's a little hard to explain, but the problem was essentially because my code was extensive, I had misplaced the clear statement, as well as where I had been pulling the info for the map from, and thus why I was getting erroneous results. Still, without everyone's help here, I would have been stuck (wastefully) trying to figure out an alternative to clear. So I really appreciate everyone's help and just want to say thank you again. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Map` interface declares `clear()` as an optional operation. However, your tag says you're using `LinkedHashMap` and the Javadocs do say the map should be empty when the call returns. Can you provide a code sample demonstrating that you can still retrieve an element by some key even after calling `clear()`?

*EDIT #1:* It occurs to me that you may mean the objects themselves are not immediately garbage collected after the mappings are removed from your `Map`; that wouldn't surprise me at all. Clearing the entries in the map doesn't mean the objects themselves have to be garbage collected or finalized right when that method completes. Can you clarify what you expect, please?

*EDIT #2* I wrote the following test case:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("one", 1);
    map.put("two", 2);
    map.put("three", 3);
    System.out.println(map);
    map.clear();
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

And observed the following output:

```
{one=1, two=2, three=3}
{}
```

Can you please provide a code sample that demonstrates exactly what you're doing, that differs from this?

Comment: I was not retrieving anything, I simply did a `System.out.println(map)` statement for the map prior to the "clear" and immediately after the "clear". And it still contains the same values prior to the "clear".

Answer (score 1):

Objects are only deleted when they're removed by the garbage collector (whose schedule is implementation-dependent). So the only thing you can really do is make sure that no references to those Objects exist in your application. If there are, then they won't be garbage collected.

You can try and poke the VM into garbage collecting by calling `System.gc();`.

Comment: Tried this, but no such luck :/